# How to create POJO class which store list of key value pair in java for a request body?

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

```
{
    "availabilityMap": {
        "2021-07-20":["10PM-11PM" , "11PM-11:30PM"],
        "2021-07-20":["9PM-10PM" , "10PM-11:00PM"]
    }
}
```

The above is the Request Body.
I have created below Dto class

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class AvailabilityDto {
    private AvailabilityMap availabilityMap;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AvailabilityDto{" +
                "availabilityMap=" + availabilityMap +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class AvailabilityMap {
    HashMap<LocalDate,List<String>> availableDates;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AvailabilityMap{" +
                "availableDates=" + availableDates +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I am new to springboot and restApi. availableDates showing null

Comment: `SortedMap<LocalDate, List<TimeRange>>`. I presume you meant to have different dates in your example, as the example is not valid JSON. (Note that if you can fix the API you can improve the structure of `TimeRange`, but this should get you going.)

Comment: Your request body is invalid since it contains two identical keys.

Comment: By mistakenly I wrote the same key value in sleep. Yes, Dates are two different values

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you may need to register `JavaTimeModule` in your Jackson `ObjectMapper` as follows so that `LocalDate` can be properly deserialized:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```

You also need the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created AvailabilityDto as below and it worked.

```
public class AvailabilityDto {
    private LinkedHashMap<LocalDate, List<String>> availabilityMap;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AvailabilityDto{" +
                "availabilityMap=" + availabilityMap +
                '}';
    }
}
```